How to notify associated custom controls for property changes?
I created a set of custom controls like a label, an edit, a button, etc. for the VCL using C++ Builder 11.2.
I also made a component which has some color and font properties and acts like a stylesheet.
So every label and edit is connected with this "stylesheet"-component and retrieve their colors and fonts etc. from it.

The stylesheet-component resides on a datamodule which is available on all forms.
Now my question is: When a color property changes, how can I notify all connected controls to update (repaint) themselves?
My first approach was to have a list of all connected controls in the stylesheet-component. the list is being filled by a method called from the setters of each control. But is this the correct way..?

Sounds fine to me. When the StyleSheet is assigned to a control, the control should register itself with the StyleSheet. Then the StyleSheet can notify all of the registered controls.
